# RevitPlugin 2021 does not contain Main method

Tags: revit-api

"RevitPlugin.exe" does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: More details please, no plugin maker would call their addin "RevitPlugin.exe" unless it was their first week on the job.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin has no `main` method. A plugin attaches to a running process that provides the `main` method. In this case, i would assume that it plugs in to `Revit.exe`.

The most effective way forward might be to work through a getting started tutorial from scratch rather than fighting the system and struggling with mistakes like this.